# Combine an array using two endpoints

Tags: php

I'm parsing through and array mapping that I would like to only pull in the media_url's, but now I also need the permalinks - How would I be able to combine the two below and then include the permalink in the foreach loop?

```
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return $entry['media_url'];
}, $array['data']);

$imageUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return $entry['permalink'];
}, $array['data']);
```

---

```
<?php foreach($mediaUrls as $mediaUrl) {
    echo "<img src='".$mediaUrl."' width='270px'/>";
  }
?>
```

I'm doing a var_dump where I'm pulling in both the media_url's and permalinks - I would just like to combine them and I'm unsure how to do that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been completed:

```php
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry['media_url'],
        'permalink' => $entry['permalink']
    ];
}, $array['data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

create an array of arrays and iterate over it:

```php
<?php
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry['media_url'],
        'permalink' => $entry['permalink']
    ];
}, $array['data']);

foreach($mediaUrls as $entry) {
    echo "<img src='{$entry['media_url']}' width='270px' />";
}
```